# MEDIANIF using CSE and requires INDIRECT

Tags: excel-formula

Constraints:
- There is a ***Calculation Sheet*** and a ***Data Sheet***
- Calculation is performed on data existing in the ***Data Sheet*** that can have any name; the name is stored in a cell in the ***Calculation Sheet*** (e.g., `B1`).
- ***Data Sheet*** has 2 header rows and an indeterminate number of records (i.e., rows that contain data).
- Not all rows contain data, though we have ensured that all data are valid numerical values.
- The particular column holding this data is stored in the ***Calculation Sheet*** (e.g., column `T`).

I know the normal CSE solution works when calculations are performed in the same sheet containing the data, e.g.,
`{MEDIAN(IF(A3:A9999 <= 3, A3:A9999))}`

Using `INDIRECT` breaks this approach, however:

`{MEDIAN(IF(INDIRECT(B1&"!"&T2&"3:"&T2&"9999")<=3, INDIRECT(B1&"!"&T2&"3:"&T2&"9999"))}`

This returns 0 instead of the median of the set of numbers less than or equal to 3.

Comment: What is the value in B1 and T2?

Comment: If your sheet has spaces then you must include `' '` around the sheet name: `INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!"&T2&"3:"&T2&"9999")`

Comment: B1 is a reference to the data sheet's name; T2 is a reference to the column holding the relevant data. [Example here](https://i.imgur.com/bhELenf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=MEDIAN(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!"&T2&"3:"&T2&"9999"),ROW(INDIRECT("3:9999"))-3,0,1),"<=3")>0,N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!"&T2&"3:"&T2&"9999"),ROW(INDIRECT("3:9999"))-3,0,1))))
```

Note that the sheet names are wrapped within single quotes in case the names have spaces, as Scott has already mentioned.

Comment: Very clever to pass INDIRECT through OFFSET before sending to IF! However, it only works if there are no blank cells and we replace "9999" with COUNT of the number of numbers in the relevant column. [Please see my test here](https://i.imgur.com/bhELenf.png)

Comment: I believe what is happening is that all the blank cells are sending "0" to the array passed to MEDIAN

Comment: I have amended the formula to exclude blank cells.  See my edited post.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for this brilliant solution! I wish I could upvote, but my score is too low!

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad I could help.  Cheers!